# How to align text in CSS vertically with this header bar

Tags: html, css

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmoll.png)

I have this header, and I want to center the text vertically, but to keep it aligned on the right, this is my current code:

```
<style>
      .top-menu {
        font-family: "Ubuntu";
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: right;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: 30px;
        /* padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;*/
        margin-right: 10px; 
      }
      .background-gray {
        background-color: gray;
        padding: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
        margin: -8px -8px 0px -8px;
      }
    </style>

<div class="background-gray">
    <h4 class="top-menu">O nama Kontakt Lokacija</h4>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to do any tricky `padding` or `margin` stuff. Simply:

```css
.top-menu {
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}
.background-gray {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-gray">
    <h4 class="top-menu">O nama Kontakt Lokacija</h4>
</div>
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7orwLgm/)

Comment: Yeah, like that but I want my background-gray to cover the top edge of the website, I dont want any white space

Comment: It sounds like whatever contains your `background-gray` div has padding or margin set. If this is the body, or some other element you don't believe you have styles set for, you should look into using a [reset sheet](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/) to clear any default browser styles. For example, try adding:
`html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`
and see if that helps

Comment: tried with html, body {, doesn't change anything

Comment: `h4` also has default styles (margin) that you'd need to override. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5xveczug/). Please do read up on reset style sheets, they will help you avoid these issues.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it worked. I used the reset style sheet and it works like a charm! Thanks a lot

Comment: Mind tossing me your discord or any direct contact to my email? If I ran into more troubles to ask you? stefanjokovic996@gmail.com Thanks a bunch

Comment: I don't like sharing my contact info, sorry. But feel free to post more questions on stack overflow and I (or someone else) would be happy to help! Best of luck on your project.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the result like this?

```css
<style>
      .top-menu {
        font-family: "Ubuntu";
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: right;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: 30px;
        /* padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;*/
        margin-right: 10px; 
      }
      .background-gray {
        display: flex;
        background-color: gray;
        padding: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
        margin: -8px -8px 0px -8px;
      }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="background-gray">
    <h4 class="top-menu">O nama Kontakt Lokacija</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Like that yeah, but I want text to be aligned to the right side